# validation expression for all over world mobile no

Tags: asp.net

I need one  validation expression for all over world mobile no 
as weel pincode...

Answer (score 1):

First of all Wish you good luck!

Secondly it will be difficult to cram all validations in a single regular expression.

Thirdly if you get one RegularExpressionValidator for each instance it will grow quite large.

The best approach will be to user ajax to validate the phone number when the field loses focus or it is changed.